# Using Python To Check Arduino Print And If Condition Met Play Sound

Tags: python, arduino

my arduino code just print out 1 and 2 wait 10 second print 0 and 0 wait 10 second and repeat.

```
int test1;
int test2;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  test1 = 1;
  test2 = 2;
  Serial.println(test1);
  Serial.println(test2);
  delay(10000);
  test1 = 0;
  test2 = 0;
  Serial.println(test1);
  Serial.println(test2);
  delay(10000);
  
}
```

my Python Code:

```
import serial
import winsound

arduinoData = serial.Serial('COM5',9600, timeout = 1) 
print("COM5")


var2 = arduinoData.readline()

print(var2)


while(1):
        var2 = arduinoData.readline().decode('ascii') 
        print(var2)

        if (var2==1):

            winsound.PlaySound("zona1.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            print("yes")

        if (var2==2):

            winsound.PlaySound("zona2.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            print("no")
```

It print out 1 2 then 0 0 then 1 2. But I can't make it work to play the sound or the print. Seem the if statement doesn't met.

I am noob in this kind of thing. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are reading *strings* from the serial port.  A string is never going to be equal to `1` or `2`, those are values of an entirely different type.  `"1"` and `"2"` would be more likely, but those will never match either, since the received strings are terminated by a newline character.  Try `"1\n"` and `"2\n"` in your comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

turn out i just need to remove the white spaces using strip.

So ('ascii').strip().